# c++ Mac Xcode: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos

I am running the following code in c++ in Xcode on Mac

```
int fibo(int x)
{
      if (x==1||x==2)
          return 1;
          else
              return fibo(x-1)+fibo(x-2);
}
```

and receiving this error cannot know why.

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can somebody help me with?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `main` function.  That's first function that gets called to "start" your program.

Add this to your file:

```
int main()
{
    fibo(10);  // calls your function with
}
```

Comment: I did that but after doing it,it says that "x" is undeclared,what should i do??

Comment: Looks like x is not defined. I suspect you meant n.

Comment: hmm no I do not think so, I gave x as an input so it should be know already for the function

Answer (score 0):

You should to implement main() function.

> The main function is called at program startup after initialization of
>   the non-local objects with static storage duration. It is the
>   designated entry point to a program that is executed in hosted
>   environment (that is, with an operating system). The entry points to
>   freestanding programs (boot loaders, OS kernels, etc) are
>   implementation-defined.
>   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cout
int fibo(int x)
{
      if (x==1||x==2)
          return 1;
          else
              return fibo(x-1)+fibo(x-2);
}

int main() 
{
      int x = 1;
      int result = fibo(x);
      std::cout << "Result: " << x; // Printing result
      return 0;
}
```